# How can i add a new child node to treeView1 under root treeNode?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

In my treeView1 i have one main node name root
Under root i have many nodes.

```
TreeNode node1 = new TreeNode("node1");
node1.Name = "node1";
treeView1.Nodes.Add(node1);
```

This will add node1 as new treeNode i need to check first if there is any treeNode already like root or any other and then add it under it. In this case node1 should be under root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select and work with the ROOT node, than add more Nodes to the collection held by ROOT. Like this for example:

```
TreeNode rootNode = treeView1.Nodes[0];  // select the root 
TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode("node1");  // new node

rootNode.Nodes.Add(newNode);   // Adding to the collection under ROOT
```

Comment: @LarsTech - thanks for the edit - I forgot the square brackets...I blame my Swedish keyboard lol

Answer (score 2):

Try checking to see of the root node exists.  If not, add it:

```
TreeNode tn = treeView1.Nodes.Find("root", false).FirstOrDefault();
if (tn == null) {
  tn = new TreeNode("root") { Name = "root" };
  treeView1.Nodes.Add(tn);
}
tn.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("node1") { Name = "node1" });
```

Comment: Nice answer, I assumed the root would simply be the first node in the collection